# Which is more correct?

Tags: grammar

Which is more correct ?

*...wine tasting in family winery run by the 8th generation of winemakers in the capital of Chianti.*

or

*...wine tasting in a family winery runs by the 8th generation of winemakers in the capital of Chianti.*

Thanks

Comment: I would use "a family winery run."

Comment: #1 has the 8th generation running (managing) the winery. #2 has the *wine tasting* running past (or running beside) the 8th generation, whatever that means.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**...wine tasting in a family winery run by the 8th generation of winemakers in the capital of Chianti.**
This definitely sounds better.

Comment: Usually ELU wants explanations and some documentation for answers.  This answer was accepted by the poster, so it probably won't get deleted.  But doesn't the poster deserve to know why it's better this way?